# In Nearby Message API How Can I get NearBy devices list who are connected??

Tags: google-nearby

Using Nearby Connection API we can get the Endpoints (means Nearby devices list)..So In Nearby Message API How Can I get NearBy devices list who are connected like NCAPI??

Answer (score 0):

The Nearby Connections API in Google Play Services 11 allows you to discover and send payloads to nearby devices.